# Auto Close Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks. Workbook A & B.

When workbook A opens, workbook B opens automatically. Auto open workbook macro is working nicely. But when I want to close workbook A, the workbook B should close together automatically. But with the auto close macro below, it doesn't seems to work. Please advise where went wrong :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Close()
If Workbooks.Close("A.xlxm") Then
ThisWorkbook.Close
End If
End Sub
```

The code above is pasted in workbook B's ThisWorkbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In workbook A in the `ThisWorkbook` code pane.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Workbooks.Item("B.xlsm").Close True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, i'm just looking for auto close worksheet macro only, cos i already have auto open workbook macro that works well for me. Is there anyway just to amend my macro that I posted above?

Comment: You cannot autoclose B on the condition A is closed without a test of A being open , unless you suppress errors and add a line to close workbook B in workbook A's Before Close event; but then your ordering of events has changed slightly.

Comment: oh i see, sorry for my limited knowledge. i already tried the code, but it won't work. Am i suppose to insert workbook B name in workbookName?

Comment: I have added a version for you to try using the Workbook Before Close event

Comment: Pleased to have helped.